# How to get the selected text block in NSTextTable

Tags: swift, nstextview, nstextcontainer

Good day,

I’ve been struggling with this recently. I would like to know how you can get the selected text block of NSTextTable so I can add blocks below and above and I would also like to know when a user is editing an NSTextTable.

Comment: In a `NSTextView`? Have you tried anything, like getting the text block from the attributes of the string? Do you want to know when the user is editing or if the edit is in a `NSTextTable`?

Comment: @Willeke I haven't tried anything. honestly don't know the direction I should go. I would like to know when a user is editing an NSTextTable and the NSTextTableBlock which is being editing in an NSTextView

Comment: Are you familiar with `NSTextView` and `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: @Willeke yeah I am

Comment: `NSParagraphStyle` has a property `textBlocks`.